# SSE _mm_dp_ps size result

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

I am starting to do operations using SSE. I want to make two dot products with `_mm_dp_ps` and save the first result in `aux_sse` and the second in `aux_sse`. B is an 8-element vector of value 1.

Since I only need two floats for each pair, I have done the following code:

```
    printf("A  \n");
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < ele; j++){
            A[i*ele+j] = i*ele+j;
            printf(" %f ", A[i*ele+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    float aux[ele*M];
    float aux2[ele*M];
    __m128 *A_sse = (__m128*) A;
    __m128 *B_sse = (__m128*) B;
    __m128 *aux_sse  = (__m128*) aux;
    __m128 *aux2_sse  = (__m128*) aux2;
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        *aux_sse =  _mm_dp_ps (*A_sse, *B_sse,  0xFF);
        printf("%f \n", aux[i]);

        B_sse ++;
        A_sse++;
        *aux2_sse = _mm_dp_ps (*A_sse, *B_sse,  0xFF);
        printf("%f \n", aux2[i]);

        B_sse --;
        A_sse ++;

        aux_sse+= sizeof(char);
        aux2_sse+= sizeof(char);
    }
```

I get the following wrong output:

```
A  
 0.000000  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000  4.000000  5.000000  6.000000  7.000000 
 8.000000  9.000000  10.000000  11.000000  12.000000  13.000000  14.000000  15.000000 
6.000000 
22.000000 
6.000000 
22.000000
```

According [this](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_dp_ps&expand=2943,2942,2946,3928,136,2435,2184,1293,2184):

> Conditionally multiply the packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements in a and b using the high 4 bits in imm8, sum the four products, and conditionally store the sum in dst using the low 4 bits of imm8.

I understand that in imm8 we specify in the elements that we want the result to be saved.

As I understand, even if the result is in the 4 elements of the output vector, if I only make an increment of one element with `aux_sse+= sizeof(char)`, the result should be overwritten and the desired result will come out. However, I see that this is not the case.

If I make the following modifications when I'm printing the result of aux and aux2 the output is correct.

```
printf("%f \n", aux[i*4]);
printf("%f \n", aux2[i*4]);
```

Output:

```
6.000000 
22.000000 
38.000000 
54.000000
```

I am using gcc compiler.
Does anyone know what the problem is? Any answer would be helpful.

EDIT:

I need the elements of aux and aux2 to correspond to each iteration:

aux[i] = dot_product performed in iteration i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aux_sse+= sizeof(char);` is a nonsensical way to write `aux_sse+=1`, i.e. advance by 16 bytes, aka 4 floats, i.e. `sizeof(__m128) == sizeof(*aux_sse) == 16`.

So if you're also accessing the array via float indices, yes, you have to scale it by 4 if you only increment `i` by 1 for every vector of 4 floats.

Normally it's easier to use `_mm_store_ps(&aux[i], v);` instead of keeping track of `__m128*` variables to access the same arrays.   And do `i+=4` so `i` is actually indexing the start of the 4-element group you have, instead of needing to scale it.  That makes it easier to write loop bounds like `i < M-3`.

Also note that you should use `alignas(16) float aux[ele*M];` if you want to do alignment-required accesses to the arrays.  GCC notices what you're doing and will align the arrays for you when it can see how they're used, but don't count on it in general.

---

**Or did you want to just store a single `float` result**, instead of 4 identical dot-products for every group of 4 inputs?  In that case you should be extracting the low scalar element, e.g. `_mm_store_ss (&aux[i], v)`. Or `_mm_cvtss_f32(v)` to get the low element of a vector as a scalar `float`.

If you want that, you can do the four 4-element dot products manually, producing 1 vector of 4 results.  `_mm_mul_ps` and then maybe 2x `_mm_hadd_ps` (SSE3) to horizontally reduce, a sort of transpose and add.  (Suggested by @mainactual)

`dpps` is 4 uops on Skylake and similar Intel CPUs (https://uops.info), so it's not great if you have multiple dot products to do.

To avoid SSE3, you'd use `_mm_shuffle_ps` ([shufps](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/shufps)) to pick elements from 2 vectors, or maybe some `_mm_unpacklo_ps` / unpackhi could be useful, or maybe the `pd` version to keep pairs of elements together.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see the problem. What I want is just store a single float result. The answer you have provided works correctly but I would like to ask if there is any way to directly save the result of a single float in each iteration in the vector aux without performing the extraction (since, it seems to me that if it is not done, it will gain in performance).

Comment: @Laune you can do four dot products with by-hand- loop unrolling and shuffling the result with `_mm_permute_ps`

Comment: @Laune: "Extracting" the low float element of a SIMD vector as a scalar is literally free in asm; a scalar `float` *is* just the low element of an XMM register (or a float in memory).  So `_mm_store_ss` simply compiles to a `movss` store.  So does `aux[i] = _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_dp_ps(...));`

Comment: @mainactual: Yes, good point, `_mm_mul_ps` and then maybe 2x `_mm_hadd_ps` to horizontally reduce, a sort of transpose and add.  `dpps` is 4 uops on Skylake (https://uops.info), so not great.  But `_mm_permute_ps` (VPERMILPS) only has 1 input vector so isn't useful for this.  If you were avoiding SSE3 haddps to limit it to only SSE2, you'd want `_mm_shuffle_ps` (shufps) to pick elements from 2 vectors, or maybe `_mm_unpacklo_ps` / unpackhi, or maybe the `pd` version to keep pairs of elements together.

Comment: Sry, I was not thinking, but simply doing `__m128 c /*and d,e,f*/ = _mm_dp_ps( a, b, imm )` for `imm` in range `0xf0+0x1`, `0xf0+0x2`, `0xf0+0x4`, `0xf0+0x8` and simply or-operation for c,d,e,f should do the unroll trick

Comment: @mainactual: If you're going to do four 4-element dot products, 4x `dpps` is not an efficient way to do it.  But yes good point that if you did want to merge 4 `dpps` results, using their immediates so you can blend with `orps` instead of `blendps` is even better.

Comment: Makes sense, but `_mm_dp_ps` is on the title, so cant remove that either, but rather inspect its parameter which is by the way pretty flexible :). And rarely `imm=0xff` is the way to go there I guess

Comment: @mainactual: The question is about debugging array indexing.  Pointing out other improvements like getting the same result a more efficient way isn't answering that at all either.  But XY questions are very normal: someone asks about the details of doing something one way, when actually it would be better and/or easier to do it a different way, and an answer pointing that out is useful.  Just because a newbie thinks they want `dpps` doesn't make it the only possible answer, e.g. for a question about a single dot product of a longer array.  You need to explain *why* not that way, but that's all